# Расчет цены при помощи SeekBar

Tags: java, android

У меня есть SeekBar , при скроллинге его значения умножается на 20000(мелочи расчетов), и сразу же отображается в другом блоке в виде цены. С Этим все хорошо. Но, что делать если я хочу скроллить SeekBar обратно при этом цена должна уменьшаться по такому же алгоритму .Спасибо

```
 SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            previousProgress = progress-1;
            if (progress >  previousProgress) {
                int c = progress * 20000;
                String pr = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                int pri = Integer.valueOf(pr);
                int pric = c + pri;
                String temp = Integer.toString(pric);
                ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(temp);

            } else {
                int c = progress * 20000;
                String pr = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                int pri = Integer.valueOf(pr);
                int pric = c - pri;
                String temp = Integer.toString(pric);
                ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(temp);

            }


        }
```

Comment: зачем эта строка - `progress = seekBar.getProgress();` ? У вас `int progress` из `onProgressChanged(` и так должен иметь значение

Comment: снаружи листенера создайте переменную и просвойте ей внутри значение прогресса. вот вам и текущее состояние

Comment: зачем нужно получать одну и ту же ссылку на виджет TextView четыре раза? получите ее один раз в начале и используйте везде в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

Ставьте условие на проверку, что предыдущее состояние было меньше или больше. Сравнивая текущие состояние с сохраненным предыдущим, вы определите направление движение seekBar, а значит узнаете нужный знак.

Comment: Я думал точно так же, но возник вопрос, как определить текущее состояние?

Comment: объявлене private previousProgress = -1; В обработчике в самом конце пишите previousProgress = progress; В самом верху сравниваете. Странно, что вы сами до этого не догадались, впрочем бывает

Comment: Я исправил по вашим советам, но в ходе очень намудрил, не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться, что именно и куда нужно написать.Исправления внес в вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: вы не идус?)) Больно код индусский)) Увы, доводить вы будете сами, т.к. задача простая, и если вам с ней погому - вы не научитесь на ошибках. сорри